# Error in output using split() method?

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to use simple split() method but the output I am getting is not Correct .I am using this code:

```
        question = newobject.ACTIVITY_LIST_OF_QUESTIONS.split("|");
```

where the newobject.ACTIVITY_LIST_OF_QUESTIONS contains 1|2|8|11|4|5|6|14|15|16|13|17|7|9|12|10 as a String so I must be getting each number in array index.

But instead of that I am getting output-

```
       1
       |
       2
       |
       8
```

Please help If someone had the same problem?

Comment: You can use String tokenizer to do the same

Comment: How are you printing your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `|` as `\\|`. Your regex is being interpreted as "empty string `or` empty string", so each position matches.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `split("\\|")`. You need to break the special meaning of the [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) `|`. You do so with `\\|`. [Note that `split()` is splitting according to regex].

```
String s = "1|2|8|11|4|5|6|14|15|16|13|17|7|9|12|10";
String[] arr = s.split("\\|");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

results in:

```
[1, 2, 8, 11, 4, 5, 6, 14, 15, 16, 13, 17, 7, 9, 12, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

A `|` is a regex metacharacter used to denote alteration. To mean a literal `|` you need to escape it as `\\|` or put it in a character class `[|]`.